# Searchcontroller only available on iOS 11 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to make my app iOS 9 compliant. But I get this error for the `navigationItem.searchController`:

```
'searchController' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer
```

How can I make this available for iOS 9 without changing every search logic through the app?

Comment: You could use a search bar and table separately

Comment: You have to use `UISearchBar` for anything less than iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the navigation item's `searchController` before iOS 11, but you can certainly use the UISearchController, just as we've done for years. Simply extract the UISearchController's `searchBar` and put it, yourself, wherever you want it in the interface. If you want it as or in the navigation bar, then put it there. For example, make it the navigation item's `titleView`.

Comment: Ye working example has been taken down... So dead link. Next time put up code.